# Count of number of test scenarios in my acceptance test suite

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have added something into my
    env.rb
which calculates a value after each scenario completion.

Say initially

```
i = 0
(after Scenario 1)
i = 0.330
(after Scenario 2)
i = 0.330 + 0.3456 = 0.6756
(so on, till end of whole test)
```

Now I want to take the average of the value i with the number of test scenarios in my acceptance suite. 
To make long story short, Is there a method to dynamically return the number of test case scenarios in the whole test suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be, but I think there's an easier way.

Instead of summing, why not append to an array? That will give you both the values and the length, from which you can calculate the sum and the mean (or any other average!).

To modify your example:

```
times = []
# (after Scenario 1)
times << 0.330
# (after Scenario 2)
times << 0.3456
# (so on, till end of whole test) 

total_time = times.inject(&:+)
num_scenarios = times.length
mean_time = total_time / num_scenarios
```